# Unable to return value from factory to service angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**my factory code**

```
.factory('appData', ['connectionManager', function($connectionManager) {
    return {
        getAppDataItem: function(apiName, params) {
            console.log('Getting value...');
            $connectionManager.sendRequest({
                'apiName': apiName,
                'params':{
                    '@key': "'" + params['@key'] + "'"
                }
            }).then(function(res){
                console.log('Retrieved data ', res.data);
                return res.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**my service code**

```
            var x = appData.getAppDataItem('getItemFromAppData', {
                    '@key': 'last_emp_id'
                });
            console.log(x);
```

I want to assign value returned by `.then()` in factory to the `var x` in my service. But I am unable to do it. please help me. I am getting value up to `.then()`. After that I am unable to pass it to the service.

Comment: Do you get any error? apiName is passed clearly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAppDataItem` function needs to return a promise:

```
.factory('appData', ['connectionManager', function($connectionManager) {
    return {
        getAppDataItem: function(apiName, params) {
            console.log('Getting value...');                
            //$connectionManager.sendRequest({
            //return promise
            return $connectionManager.sendRequest({
                'apiName': apiName,
                'params':{
                    '@key': "'" + params['@key'] + "'"
                }
            }).then(function(res){
                console.log('Retrieved data ', res.data);
                return res.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

The client code should use the promise's `.then` method to access the data.

```
var promise = appData.getAppDataItem('getItemFromAppData', {
        '@key': 'last_emp_id'
    });
promise.then( function (x) {
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any other way to do it?
This is fine but I want to know

Comment: Another way is to return an object reference that will later be filled in with the data. But in that case I recommend that the promise be added to the object as a property named `$promise`.